# Function overloading in multiple inheritance diamond problem in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

This is just a question on the best practices to follow for function overloading in a diamond problem in multiple inheritance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "In A" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public virtual A {
    public:
    virtual void print() {
        A::print();
        cout << "In B" << endl;
    }
};

class C : public virtual A {
    public:
    virtual void print() {
        A::print();
        cout << "In C" << endl;
    }
};

class D : public virtual B, public virtual C {
    public:
    virtual void print() {
        B::print();
        C::print();
        cout << "In D" << endl;
    }
};
```

Here, base class `class A` implements a `print()` function which is overloaded in derived classes `class B` and `class C`. However, the derived classes `class B` and `class C` also require the base class `print()` function, so they have calls to the base class `print()` function using `A::print()`.

```
A a;
B b;
C c;
```

`a.print();`

Output:

```
In A
```

`b.print();`

Output:

```
In A
In B
```

`c.print();`

Output:

```
In A
In C
```

`class D` is derived from `class B` and `class C`.

`class D` also needs to overload the `print()` function and call all the print functions of its parent classes `class B` and `class C` as well as grandparent class `class A`.

Using `B::print(); C::print();` in the overloaded `print()` function of `class D`:

`d.print();`

Output:

```
In A
In B
In A
In C
In D
```

which is expected since the overloaded `print()` functions in `class B` and `class C` both have calls to `A::print()`.

What is the best practice to overload the `print()` function in `class D` so that:

`d.print();`

Output:

```
In A
In B
In C
In D
```

given that classes `class A`, `class B` and `class C` cannot be modified.

Comment: Given that you can't modify the A,B,C classes, and both B and C call A, there's no way you can achieve the output of A,B,C,D via any changes to inheritance. Even if you didn't inherit from B and C, and just insitantiated B and C and called print on them, you would still end up with A duplicated.

Comment: What could be the solution if classes A, B and C were allowed to be modified?

Comment: Re: "function which is overloaded in derived classes" -- the function is not **overloaded**, it's **overridden**. Overloading occurs when there are two declarations of the same function **in the same scope**. Overriding occurs when a derived class has a function with the same name and signature as a function in one of its base classes.